# target variable in dynamic target

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a bit more complex Makefile with dynamically generated targets like this:

```
COMPONENTS = foo bar lipsum

define TEST_template =
  .PHONY: test-$(1)
  test-$(1):
    @echo test
endef
$(foreach cmpnt,$(COMPONENTS),$(eval $(call TEST_template,$(cmpnt))))
```

But now I'd like to add a target-specific variable to this target. With non-dynamic targets this works nicely:

```
test: VAR_ONE=1
test:
    @echo "VAR_ONE=$(VAR_ONE)"
```

But combining these two is not working

```
COMPONENTS = foo bar lipsum

define TEST_template =
  .PHONY: test2-$(1)
  test2-$(1): VAR_ONE=1
  test2-$(1):
    @echo "test - VAR_ONE=$(VAR_ONE)"
endef
$(foreach cmpnt,$(COMPONENTS),$(eval $(call TEST_template,$(cmpnt))))
```

Now running `make test2-foo` returns `test - VAR_ONE=`, so it seems the variable is not being set.

Is this even possible? I've been trying to achieve this for a couple of days now but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape any variable reference inside the `define` that you don't want to be interpreted by the `call`.  So it's:

```
define TEST_template =
  .PHONY: test2-$(1)
  test2-$(1): VAR_ONE=1
  test2-$(1):
        @echo "test - VAR_ONE=$$(VAR_ONE)"
endef
```

A good rule of thumb (although as with anything, there are exceptions) is that when defining a variable to be used with a `call`/`eval` pair, the arguments to `call` (e.g., `$1`, `$2` etc.) should be referenced directly and all other variables should be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write

```
    @echo "test - VAR_ONE=$$(VAR_ONE)"
```

(note the double `$$`). See `info make`

> It's important to realize that the 'eval' argument is expanded
>   *twice*; first by the 'eval' function, then the results of that expansion are expanded again when they are parsed as makefile syntax.
>   This means you may need to provide extra levels of escaping for "$"